# Fadein FadeOut not working in IE8

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, fadein, fade

I am using fade in and fade out to fade a gradient png in order to read text, it is a png-24  the code is very simple yet IE8 wont fade, it just pops in and pops out
 $(document).ready(function() {

```
        $('#menu').hover(function() {
            $('#gradient').fadeIn('slow');
        }, function() {
            $('#gradient').fadeOut('fast');
        });
    });
```

Comment: CSS Opacity is "faked" in IE using the alpha filter... this *may* be something that you might not be able to overcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#menu').hover(function() {
        $('#gradient').fadeIn('slow');
     }, function() {
        $('#gradient').fadeOut('fast');
    });
}); 
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="menu" style="background:red; height:200; width:200px;">

 <input type="file" id="gradient" style="display:none" />

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

its work fine........

Comment: This isn't using a **PNG** image... I believe that's where @goetzs' issue with the fadeIn/fadeOut is coming from.  Basic fadeIn/fadeOut works fine in IE6/IE7/IE8.